# How to automatically set ManyToMany relationship with user

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

How to automatically set owner field with the user which creates this event?

Event model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    describe = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    type_of_event = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_OF_EVENT_CHOICE, default=0)
    img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField()
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, verbose_name='City', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    ticket_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Contact email',
                              validators=[validate_email])
```

Event`s view:

```
class CreateEventView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = EventDetailSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Event`s serializer:

```
class EventDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'img', 'type_of_event', 'describe', 'event_date', 'city', 'address',
                  'ticket_price', 'email']
```

Comment: I think now it's not `ManyToMany`, it's rather `ManyToOne`. Do want it to be changed? Or do you want the answer to save the user when the event is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by overriding the `perform_create` method of your `CreateEventView`, something like this:

```py
class CreateEventView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = EventDetailSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

And as David pointed out, keep in mind that a `ForeignKey` is **not** a a many-to-many relation, that would be a `ManyToManyField`. Given the context, I assume the `ForeignKey` (owner) is actually the desired behavior, so all good.