# Automatically set author on POST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a events administration app powered by Django APIRest. When a user post a event is considered the author and I wonder what is the most elegant/professional way to do it:

1. Override the post view
2. Override the create model method
3. Override the save serializer method

This is what I currently have (option 1)
The models.py:

```
class Events(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dateday = models.DateTimeField()
    start_hour = models.TimeField(null=True)
    end_hour = models.TimeField(null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The serializers.py:

```
#...
class EventsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Events
        fields = '__all__'

class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    events = EventsSerializer(many=False,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
#...
```

The views.py:

```
#...
class EventsList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Events.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventsSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        request.data['author'] = request.user.pk
        return super().post(request)
#...
```

It works, but I still have to prevent changing the author in a PUT request. There's a better way to minimize code or make it reusable?

I tried the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72355316/how-to-automatically-set-manytomany-relationship-with-user):

```
class EventsList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Events.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventsSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

but it does not work: a POST with a body without author the response is that the field author is required.

Comment: Adding `author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)` to the `EventsSerializer` makes [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72355316/how-to-automatically-set-manytomany-relationship-with-user) work.